# DSN connection and password with @

Tags: php, database, passwords, symbols, dsn

I think about switching to DB access library that uses DSN connection - connect("mysql://login:password@database?options"). DSN uses @ as a separator. Does it mean that the password cannot contain @ symbol? Is there other restrictions?

Comment: can you provide your pass later, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any special characters can be tricky with DSNs, particularly if the language / platform escaping or special character rules decide to intervene.

For [Pear style DSNs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php), which I suppose you are using, it should be safe to use [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to protect special characters (`@ == %40`) from being translated incorrectly.