# error in codeigniter login system

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

So i got this error
Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\models\user.php on line 15

View

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>
 <label for="username">Username:</label>
 <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
 <br/>
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

Controller login:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
$this->load->helper(array('form'));
    $this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('login_view');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

}

?>
```

Controller Verify

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
}

function index()
{
//This method will have the credentials validation
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password',         'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
 //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
 $this->load->view('login_view');
}
else
{
 //Go to private area
 redirect('home', 'refresh');
}

}

function check_database($password)
{
//Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
$username = $this->input->post('username');

//query the database
$result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

if($result)
{
 $sess_array = array();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
   $sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
 }
 return TRUE;
}
else
{
 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
 return false;
}
}
}
?>
```

Model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class User extends CI_Model
{
function login($username, $password)
{
$this -> db -> select('gebruiker_id, gebruikersnaam, wachtwoord');
$this -> db -> from('gebruikers');
$this -> db -> where('gebruikersnaam', $username);
$this -> db -> where('wachtwoord', MD5($password));
$this -> db -> limit(1);

$query = $this -> db -> get();

if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
{
 return $query->result();
}
else
{
 return false;
}
}
}
?>
```

I tried looking up the answer on different questions but my problem couldn't be fixed by the given answers.

I have looked around on different websites and i just can't find the answer.

I am quite new at codeigniter and it proofs to be very handy when you get the code to work

Comment: If you are new to code igniter, I would suggest you checking out Laravel. CI is dead.

Comment: try removing spaces between -> and others try use  $query->num_rows()

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have declared the database class ($autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);) in the autoload file in the config folder, Also you can check your output using var_dump()

Edited

Query is set to FALSE instead of giving a result means it fails. I think your database connection doesn't work at all. So you can check and try to connect using DSN.

Reference - [How to connect to a User DSN using codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947924/how-to-connect-to-a-user-dsn-using-codeigniter)

Comment: var_dump($query) gives bool(false). $autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’); is in the autoload file

Answer (score 0):

I think that a workaround would be nice for you. Instead of checking for number of rows, check if the result is null or not.

Try adding **->result()** in the query already, it works OK, like:

```
$dataFromBase = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, MyWhereArguments)->result(); // or any query you want.
```

In this way, I already have the result format, object format, and then I check if it's null or not, like:

```
if ($dataFromBase != null) {
    // handle your result
}
```

But still, it is a little weird that your num_rows() doesn't work, I did some tests and It has worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

instead of this

```
 if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
```

write this

```
 if($query->num_rows()==1)
```

check if it is working or not

Comment: what erroor u r getting now? remove all spaces between arrow above the $query->num_rows().

Comment: same error. removed all the spaces. Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\models\user.php on line 15

Comment: write var_dump($query->num_rows()); and see what o/p coming.tell me the o/p   and instead of this $this -> db ->where('gebruikersnaam', $username);$this -> db -> where('wachtwoord', MD5($password));                        write this $where=array('gebruikersnaam'=>$username,
   'wachtwoord'=> MD5($password)
   );

$this->db->where($where); may be it will work

Comment: instead of the %query-> ... or on the next line?

Comment: below the $query=$this->db->get(); write var_dum($query->num_rows()); see my previous edited comment

Comment: the spaces are not a problem i think